# PowerShell: How to limit string to N characters?

Tags: powershell

substring complains when I try to limit a string to 10 characters which is not 10 or more characters in length. I know I can test the length but I would like to know if there is a single cmdlet which will do what I need.

```
PS C:\> "12345".substring(0,5)
12345

PS C:\> "12345".substring(0,10)
Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length"
At line:1 char:18
+ "12345".substring( <<<< 0,10)
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Do you need exactly a cmdlet? I wonder why you don't like getting length. If it's part of a script, then it looks fine.

```
$s = "12345"
$s.substring(0, [System.Math]::Min(10, $s.Length))
```

Comment: Thanks that will work fine. I was looking for "least" and "greatest" functions and was not aware of this method.

Comment: It is from the .Net standard library. When you don't find a cmdlet that does what you want, check for a method that does this in .Net.

Comment: This is only correct for startIndex = 0. Otherwise, substract that from the second argument for Min. ie `@s.substring(3, [System.Math]::Min(10, $s.Length - 3))`

Answer (score 33):

Using the substring function has it's limitations and requires you to first capture the length of the string. Granted this does work you can do it without that limitation.

The following will return the first 5 characters of the string

```
"1234567890"[0..4] -join ""     # returns the string '12345'
```

And this will work on strings that are shorter than desired length

```
"1234567890"[0..1000] -join ""  # returns the string '1234567890'
```

Comment: You answer the question in first example. Simple and easy. Thanks! (+1) But, I am not sure what your second example is trying to do - the example itself shows nothing/no change to string. Either a bad example, doesn't work as intended, or not explained adequately..

Comment: @B.Shea he is showing that it won't break if the string you are truncating isn't long enough to actually truncate.  Basically it's safe to use on short strings and long strings.  This lets you avoid doing an if statement before truncation.

Comment: This is a great technique, but a `$null` string variable throws an error. Fix it by wrapping the variable in a string: `$trimmed = "$($myObject.Property)"[0..9] -join ""`

Comment: Indexing past the end of the string doesn't work with `Set-StrictMode -Version Latest`: Fails with "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Answer (score 3):

You can load and use other libraries and use their string functions, for example the visual 
basic string functions work nicely for what you want to do

call once per session
`>[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("microsoft.visualbasic")`

then use various vb string functions

```
>[microsoft.visualbasic.strings]::left("12345",10)
12345
```

or

```
>[microsoft.visualbasic.strings]::mid("12345",1,10)
12345
```

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers didn't suit my purposes (no offence!) so I took Denomales suggestion above and rolled it into a function which I thought I'd share:

```
function Trim-Length {
param (
    [parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True)] [string] $Str
  , [parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)] [int] $Length
)
    $Str[0..($Length-1)] -join ""
}
```

Example usages:

```
"1234567" | Trim-Length 4    # returns: "1234"
"1234" | Trim-Length 99      # returns: "1234"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dmitry for the answer, I turned it into a function and made it so it is 1 based as opposed to 0 based.

```
function acme-substr ([string]$str, $start, $end) {
   $str.substring($start-1, [System.Math]::Min($str.Length-1, $end))
}

> $foo="0"*20
> $foo
00000000000000000000
> acme-substr $foo 1 5
00000
```

Answer (score 0):

How about padding first.

```
$s = "12345"
$s.PadRight(10).Substring(0,10).TrimEnd() # returns "12345"
```